# How to pass Oracle Wallet auth to sh script?

Tags: oracle, scripting, wallet

I am running an Oracle DB update script that requires password. I have Oracle wallet installed. How to pass Oracle wallet to sh script so that I don't have to enter password when running the script?

I have my sqlnet.ora

```
sqlnet.expire_time=60
sqlnet.inbound_connect_timeout=300
sqlnet.allowed_logon_version_server=10
sqlnet.allowed_logon_version_client=10

WALLET_LOCATION =
(SOURCE =
   (METHOD = FILE)
      (METHOD_DATA =
          (DIRECTORY = /oracle/app/oracle/product/base19/19/network/admin/wallet)
   )
)

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
```

Credentials are correctly installed:
    $ mkstore -wrl "/oracle/app/oracle/product/base19/19/network/admin/wallet" -listCredential

```
Oracle Secret Store Tool Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.4.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 2004, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Enter wallet password:   
List credential (index: connect_string username)
1: SID USER PASSWORD
```

I am running a script update_sql.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlplus cobrball @release.sql
```

release.sql:

```
spool release.log;
exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an auto-login wallet.

[Creating an Auto-Login Wallet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/using-the-orapki-utility-to-manage-pki-elements.html#GUID-20C270E3-AC85-47F3-A1C2-D095665B7B72)

Then connect to the database using the below syntax:

`sqlplus /@connect_string @release.sql`

`connect_strings` must be the same `connect_string` that is stored in the wallet. Otherwise the credentials in the wallet will not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the name of the required wallet entry to sqlplus in this form:

```
sqlplus /@entry-name
```

In your case, I tihnk this will be

```
sqlplus /@SID
```

Note that you should have a TNS Alias with the *same name* (here "SID"), that describes how the client should get to the target database.

Personally, I'd suggest naming your wallet entries with something more purposeful than just *where* they're going.  If you ever find yourself needing *two* connections to the *same* database for *different* purposes, then having two separate wallet entries makes that simplicity itself.

```
mkstore -wrl . -createCredential SID_read_only user1 password1 
mkstore -wrl . -createCredential SID_update    user2 password2
```

If you only have one wallet entry that goes to the database, then it might mean one or other process running with far more (or less) privileges than it actually requires.